# Can I transfer a Master-Detail from Lead to Account?

Tags: administration, setup

We have custom objects that are used to capture test scores for people who apply to our programs, such as GMAT. Currently, these have a Master-Detail relationship to Accounts, but I would like to start capturing this data at the Lead stage. Leads are not an option, however, for Master-Detail relationships.

Is there a way to add Master-Detail relationships to Leads and have them transfer when converted to Accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep track of that much information about a Lead, you may want to consider simply eliminating Leads from your Sales process, or converting to an Account and Contact as soon as you have a Test Score.

This will eliminate duplicating effort and writing custom code to properly convert this relationship. My advice on Leads is generally to convert them as soon as things get interesting or complicated, which seems like the scenario you're describing.

Comment: That sounds like very good advice.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a Lead lookup on the object and then have trigger logic that runs on Lead Conversion to link the record associated with the lead to the Account by setting the Master account lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfect Trigger scenario.First establish relationship between Leads and that custom object .Now during Lead conversion you can definately have a trigget to meet your requirements .Be careful of the check box we have on lead which decides whether to fire Trigger or Not

Comment: The checkbox is just for firing the before triggers after lead conversion. The after trigger fires anyway. Transfer of records is best done in the after trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As of Summer '12, lookup fields can now have Master-Detail style characteristics including requiredness and directions what to do when you delete the parent lookup record. Check out: http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Summer12/lookup+relationship+enhancements for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't really address my needs; we had wanted to transfer a Master-Detail from a Lead to the Account but that isn't (easily) possible.